# What is the best way to determine if my users can accept cookies/sessions

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I need some help with some logic for my buying process on my website.

We have a 4 step buying process: results, customer details, payment details, order confirmation.

The results page simply outputs prices to the screen based on some query string parameters.

I then save lots of information to PHP Sessions variables for later use.

On the 2nd stage, the customer stage, I want to output some of these session variables to the screen which for the most part works.

In my code, one of the first things I do is check the existence of one of the session variables I set on the results page, just to check we are in business and the customers quote info is saving properly.

I have set up warning emails to myself to notify me when a user lands on either the customer or payment stage of the booking process but apparently the first session variable does not exist. I then display a friendly error message asking if they have enabled cookies in their browser.

We seem to be getting a lot of these warnings emails, alarmingly high. It doesn't feel like an accurate statistic of how many customers could arrive without cookies enabled.

The email alerts me of the current URL, the ref URL if there was one, the users IP address, and an output of all Session Vars they have saved (always none of course!)

I'm just stumped what to do next - are these really users or bots hitting the results page without cookies enabled which means they'll fail the test on the next page or could it be something else?

I have session_start() on the top of each of these buying pages so it's nothing like that.

Here's my customer page:

```
<?php

require_once "../includes/common.php";

$quoteShared        = new quoteShared();

// Check if this is a direct page hit
if (requestSession("sessionnumber") == "") {

    echo $quoteShared->directHit();
    die;
```

common.php has session_start() at the top.

```
function requestSession($xParam) {
    $value = "";

    if (isset($_SESSION[$xParam]))
    {
        if ($_SESSION[$xParam] != "") {
            $value = $_SESSION[$xParam];
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: you need to set a cookie, then check if you get that cookie back on the user's next request. simply calling setcookie() is pointless - you can sent all the headers you want, it's entirely up to the client to actually honor the set-cookie header.

Comment: I would get the helper function out of the way first of all. If you are setting $_SESSION["sessionnumber"] on a previous page, make the check on that value directly. How do users get from the previous page? If it's a redirect, make sure you're calling `session_write_close()` before doing that.

Comment: results to customer details is form POST with no redirect. I feel like I need to integrate POST/REDIRECT/GET but I haven't yet. $_SESSION["sessionnumber"] is indeed being set at start of results, so my requestSession function should work fine for most people on customer right?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a red hearing like bots going through my results page to the customer page - they wouldn't accept Sessions would they, hence throwing the errors? Perhaps I need some help in my warning emails to help me identify real potential customers who can't access my customer page, against automated bots that I don't care about?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in javascript also, this way :

```
function cookiesAreEnabled()
{   
    var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? 1 : 0;  

    if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && cookieEnabled == 0){   
    document.cookie="testcookie";   
    cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("test­cookie") != -1) ? 1 : 0; 
    }   

  return cookieEnabled == 1;
}
```

**BEST WAY PHP**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_GET['testing'])){
        setcookie('cookietest', 'somevalue', time()+3600);
        header("location: cookie.php?testing=1");
    }else{
        if(isset($_COOKIE['cookietest']) && $_COOKIE['cookietest'] == 'somevalue'){
            echo 'cookie enabled';
        }else{
            echo 'cookie not enabled';
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answers but I'm not just looking for a coding solution to working out if they have cookies enabled. Using the FF Web developer toolbar, if I disable cookies I get the warning message on the customer page as expected. I just want to be able to more accurately log which of the people that are triggering this warning are actual users, legimately don't  have cookies enabled, perhaps have a plug in installed that is blocking cookies or could even be a bot.

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstood, i can tell you how to check a cookie but i cannot tell u if a bot is hitting your website, as a server admin your job is to investigate logs on you server and find patterns